# Java semaphore + No synchronization lock is held when acquire() is called

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am not able to understand the meaning of below line which is provided on link [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2013/130619-j101-java-concurrency-part-1.html?page=6)

> No synchronization lock is held when acquire() is called because that would prevent an item from being returned to the pool.

Kindly help me understanding this.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of the article and code explanation, the above line says that whenever acquire() method is being called, it does not *actually* lock the resource it is *trying* to acquire. Why it is so?

**Semaphore is like sleeping lock. When a task attempts to acquire a semaphore that is already held, the semaphore places the task onto a wait queue and puts the task to sleep.**

Because from semaphore usage, you are requesting to get the lock, and *waiting in a queue*. You will get the lock only when you are actually given the resource.

Answer (score 0):

Look on [this](http://www.jconcurrent.com/Semaphore.html) animated video it help you